# Error and warnings with C program

Tags: c

I have an error on line 41: expected expression before 'int'
                   line 45: suggest parentheses around comparison in operand of '&'

Also I wanted to make sure if the code from 43-45 made sense.

I am posting on this forum for the first time and I am new to C so please bear with the amateur nature of this post

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main(void)

{
 // LOCAL DECLARATIONS

 int bricks; //the number of bricks available
 int spheres; //the number of spheres available
 int prisms; //the number of prisms available
 int final_string(int bricks, int spheres, int prisms); //the longest possible string with the given shapes in an alternating fashion

 // EXECUTABLE STATEMENTS

 printf("\nEnter the number of bricks: ");
 scanf("%d", &bricks);
 printf("Enter the number of spheres: ");
 scanf("%d", &spheres);
 printf("Enter the number of prisms: ");
 scanf("%d", &prisms);
 printf("\nLongest possible string of alternating shapes usuing only two different shapes: %d", int final_string(int bricks, int spheres, int prisms));

 int final_string(int bricks,int spheres,int prisms);
{
 return bricks * (bricks > spheres & bricks > prisms) + spheres * (spheres > bricks & spheres > prisms) + prisms * (prisms > bricks & prisms > spheres);
}

return(0);
```

Comment: You multiply a bool with an integer.This is certainly no right.

Comment: Really? "Line 41 and 45" is a useful *title* for a question?!

Comment: the code in 43-45 doesn't make sense, to answer your question. It looks like you are trying to define a function inside `main`

Comment: Makes one say: "Run code run. C code run."

Comment: Question filter should get more sophisticated on SO now.

Comment: @PHIfounder - improvement is not needed on the terminal but on its operator :)

Comment: Sorry about the messy code. I will improve and fix things. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Remove all the `int`s from the line:

   ```
   printf("\nLongest possible string of alternating shapes usuing only two different shapes: %d", int final_string(int bricks, int spheres, int prisms));
   ```
2. Remove the semicolon after the function signature in the definition of `final_string`
3. Move `final_string` outside of `main`
4. Use the logical `&&` operator instead of the bitwise `&`
5. Buy and read [a C book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)
6. In the future ask "questions" like this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

The line,

```
printf("\nLongest possible string of alternating shapes usuing only two different shapes: %d",  int final_string(int bricks, int spheres, int prisms));
```

is wrong. In this line, `int final_string(int bricks, int spheres, int prisms)` is declaration of function and not calling it.
Replace it with `final_string(bricks, spheres, prisms)`.

And define that function outside `main`. In `C`, function can't nest. So your corrected code would look,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main(void)
{
    // LOCAL DECLARATIONS

   int bricks; //the number of bricks available
   int spheres; //the number of spheres available
   int prisms; //the number of prisms available
   int final_string(int bricks, int spheres, int prisms); //the longest possible string with the given shapes in an alternating fashion

   // EXECUTABLE STATEMENTS

   printf("\nEnter the number of bricks: ");
   scanf("%d", &bricks);
   printf("Enter the number of spheres: ");
   scanf("%d", &spheres);
   printf("Enter the number of prisms: ");
   scanf("%d", &prisms);
   printf("\nLongest possible string of alternating shapes usuing only two different   shapes: %d", final_string( bricks,  spheres, prisms));
   return(0);
}

int final_string(int bricks,int spheres,int prisms)
{
    return bricks * (bricks > spheres & bricks > prisms) + spheres * (spheres > bricks & spheres > prisms) + prisms * (prisms > bricks & prisms > spheres);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go :

http://cfiddle.net/TyZAKw

As said above you put too many "int"
";" after the function signature when implementing it
and & instead of &&